# Get every day of week within date range using hibernate query

Tags: hibernate

How do you get the dates of every monday, thursday and friday between 1 Jan 2014 to 5 Feb 2014?

If hibernate query cannot achieve it, any work-around suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about why you'd want to use a query to get this information, unless there is more to your question.

I would probably just do this using the Joda library (assuming you're using Java).

Something like:

```
LocalDate currentDate = new LocalDate(2014, 1, 1);
LocalDate endDate = new LocalDate(2014, 2, 5);

while(currentDate.isBefore(endDate)) {

  if (currentDate.getDayOfWeek() == 1 || currentDate.getDayOfWeek() == 4 ||     currentDate.getDayOfWeek() == 5) {
    System.out.println(currentDate.toString());
  }
  currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! I'm thinking if there are 100k records being pulled out and process in memory, will there be any issue?

Comment: You only need to do this once since the answer isn't going to change.